# Styling a shop widget to look completely different

Tags: javascript, css, widget, styling

I have a shop widget that isn't the most appealing that I get from my affiliate network, but I would like to change the appearance of it to make it look cleaner and nicer.  If you visit the jsfiddle and delete the css you can see the original widget.  Right now I have just been using chrome developer and css to change the appearance of the widget.  But I'm stuck right now because I can't figure out how to add space between the different items in the widget.  I would like 4 or 5 items per row with some space between them.  Kind of like this site (https://thestylescribe.com/shop/) but without the black border and hover info.  She uses the same widget as me, so I know it is possible to style it differently.  Can anyone help me out in making it look like this.

jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/rayfm9cp/

```css
.bo-garden {
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    width:100% !important;
    overflow: visible !important;
    min-width:700px !important;
}
.bo-box {
    background: none !important;
    border: none !important;
}
.bo-con:after, .bo-con:before {
    background: none !important;
}
img.bo-img{
    width: 200px !important;
    height: 300px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="boutique-widget" data-widget-id="625672"><script type="text/javascript">!function(d,s,id){var e, p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)) {e = d.createElement(s);e.id = id;e.src = p + '://' + 'widgets.rewardstyle.com' + '/js/boutique.js';d.body.appendChild(e);}if(typeof window.__boutique === 'object') if(d.readyState === 'complete') {window.__boutique.init();}}(document, 'script', 'boutique-script');</script><div class="rs-adblock"><img src="//assets.rewardstyle.com/production/c108ac3fc3225bcc7f580567db42a46920d79336/images/search/350.gif" onerror="this.parentNode.innerHTML='Disable your ad blocking software to view this content.'" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;" /><noscript>JavaScript is currently disabled in this browser. Reactivate it to view this content.</noscript></div></div>
```

Comment: The `.bo-con` elements are each positioned absolutely. You would either have to override that to put them back into the normal flow of the document or alter their specific positions.

Comment: `.bo-img{
    width: 200px !important;
    height: 300px !important;
}` results in overding the original image aspect ratio as you are using fixed points. You're better off with `.bo-img{
    max-width: 200px;
    max-height: 300px
}` which would allow CSS to scale the images properly

Comment: But I would like all of the images to be that size (200x300).

Comment: If the images were not produced with the same aspect ratio, then forcing them all to be a specific height and width will result in distortion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little tricky because you would have to use !important in your CSS. I think the following gives you what you need:

```
.bo-garden {
   min-height: 5055px;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
   align-items: center;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.bo-con {
  margin: 0!important;
  position: relative!important;
  top: 0!important;
  left: 0!important;
  width: 30%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it looks a lot better.  Would you know how to center the widget? As of now it is slightly off centered on the page.  Also is it possible to add a load more button like the blog I mentioned has? (https://thestylescribe.com/shop/) - this is what the code looks like so far with your edits - https://jsfiddle.net/06m0xzd7/